# Make Windows apps in the taskbar open up another icon for that instance

Tags: windows, windows-10

Okay so I don't really know how to explain what I mean. It will be easier with photos.

[image: click]

Here is how my taskbar looks. If I click on the Windows Explorer app, it will look like this.

[image: click]

After I click the icon for that app, I want it to remain the same like in the first photo, and the icon for that instance to appear separately. So I would like it like this:

[image: click]

I know this can be done because that's how I had it until I reinstalled my Windows. Now I can't remember how did I do that.

Thanks.

EDIT:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynpvZ.png)

I edited it in Photoshop. Here is how I would like it to appear. So I opened up another instance of file explorer, but it doesn't stack up with the first.

Comment: Go to Windows Settings (Win+I) > Personalization > Taskbar > Combine taskbar buttons > Always, hide labels.

Comment: I don't get the expected result.

Comment: I use "combine when the taskbar is full" and I get your result, except that the taskbar entries are in the quick launch area. You would need to remove explorer from quick launch to achieve your placement. (By the way, your second image is confusing, because it shows an instance of `paint`, not `explorer`.)

Comment: I'm sorry for that being confusing. It just happened to be there. How can I set it to quick launch? I think that might work.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, right-click on the taskbar, select properties, on the taskbar tab  just a few lines down  find "taskbar buttons:" from the pulldown menu select "never combine".

Comment: @Larryc it didn't work. Check my edit please.

Comment: @Larryc  maybe `never combine` comes in effect after restarting `explorer.exe` using `Task Manager`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the Desktop -> New -> Shortcut -> Write `explorer.exe` as target, and click on Next and Finish.

Now, right click on this shorcut, and "Pin to taskbar".

You can delete the desktop shortcut, and try the button that just appeared on the taskbar.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I thought about this since the beginning, but I thought there might be another solution. In the end, I used this one. Thanks :)

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu why didn't you upvote the person who spent time to helped you?